# How to make a thread stop excution (eg: std::this_thread::sleep_for) for an accturate interval

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am currently making a small discord bot that can play music to improve my skill. That's why i don't use any discord lib.
I want the music as smooth as possible, but when i played some piece of music, the music produced is very choppy.
here is my code:

```
concurrency::task<void> play(std::string id) {
            auto shared_token = std::make_shared<concurrency::cancellation_token*>(&p_token);
            auto shared_running = std::make_shared<bool*>(&running);
            return concurrency::create_task([this, id, shared_token] {
                audio* source = new audio(id); // create a s16le binary stream using FFMPEG
                speak();                       // sending speak packet
                printf("creating opus encoder\n");
                const unsigned short FRAME_MILLIS = 20;
                const unsigned short FRAME_SIZE = 960;
                const unsigned short SAMPLE_RATE = 48000;
                const unsigned short CHANNELS = 2;
                const unsigned int BITRATE = 64000;
                #define MAX_PACKET_SIZE FRAME_SIZE * 5
                int error;
                OpusEncoder* encoder = opus_encoder_create(SAMPLE_RATE, CHANNELS, OPUS_APPLICATION_AUDIO, &error);
                if (error < 0) {
                    throw "failed to create opus encoder: " + std::string(opus_strerror(error));
                }

                error = opus_encoder_ctl(encoder, OPUS_SET_BITRATE(BITRATE));
                if (error < 0) {
                    throw "failed to set bitrate for opus encoder: " + std::string(opus_strerror(error));
                }

                if (sodium_init() == -1) {
                    throw "libsodium initialisation failed";
                }

                int num_opus_bytes;
                unsigned char* pcm_data = new unsigned char[FRAME_SIZE * CHANNELS * 2];
                opus_int16* in_data;
                std::vector<unsigned char> opus_data(MAX_PACKET_SIZE);

                class timer_event {
                    bool is_set = false;

                public:
                    bool get_is_set() { return is_set; };
                    void set() { is_set = true; };
                    void unset() { is_set = false; };
                };

                timer_event* run_timer = new timer_event();
                run_timer->set();

                //this is the send loop
                concurrency::create_task([run_timer, this, shared_token] {
                    while (run_timer->get_is_set()) {
                        speak();
                        int i = 0;
                        while (i < 15) {
                            utils::sleep(1000);
                            if (run_timer->get_is_set() == false) {
                                std::cout << "Stop sending speak packet due to turn off\n";
                                concurrency::cancel_current_task();
                                return;
                            }
                            if ((*shared_token)->is_canceled()) {
                                std::cout << "Stop sending speak packet due to cancel\n";
                                concurrency::cancel_current_task();
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }});
                std::deque<std::string>* buffer = new std::deque<std::string>();
                auto timer = concurrency::create_task([run_timer, this, buffer, FRAME_MILLIS, shared_token] {
                    while (run_timer->get_is_set() || buffer->size() > 0) {
                        utils::sleep(5 * FRAME_MILLIS); //std::this_thread::sleep_for
                        int loop = 0;
                        int sent = 0;
                        auto start = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
                        while (buffer->size() > 0) {
                            if (udpclient.send(buffer->front()) != 0) { //send frame
                            //udpclient.send ~ winsock sendto
                                std::cout << "Stop sendding voice data due to udp error\n";
                                return;
                            }
                            buffer->pop_front();
                            if ((*shared_token)->is_canceled()) {
                                std::cout << "Stop sending voice data due to cancel\n";
                                concurrency::cancel_current_task();
                            }
                            sent++; //count sent frame

                            //calculate next time point we should (in theory) send next frame and store in *delay*
                            long long next_time = (long long)(sent+1) * (long long)(FRAME_MILLIS) * 1000 ;
                            auto now = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
                            long long mcs_elapsed = (boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::microseconds>(now - start)).count(); // elapsed time from start loop
                            long long delay = std::max((long long)0, (next_time - mcs_elapsed));
                            //wait for next time point
                            boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(context_io);
                            timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::microseconds(delay));
                            timer.wait();
                        }     
                    }
                    });
                unsigned short _sequence = 0;
                unsigned int _timestamp = 0;
                while (1) {
                    if (buffer->size() >= 50) {
                        utils::sleep(FRAME_MILLIS);
                    }

                    if (source->read((char*)pcm_data, FRAME_SIZE * CHANNELS * 2) != true) 
                        break;
                    if ((*shared_token)->is_canceled()) {
                        std::cout << "Stop encoding due to cancel\n";
                        break;
                    }

                    in_data = (opus_int16*)pcm_data;
                    num_opus_bytes = opus_encode(encoder, in_data, FRAME_SIZE, opus_data.data(), MAX_PACKET_SIZE);
                    if (num_opus_bytes <= 0) {
                        throw "failed to encode frame: " + std::string(opus_strerror(num_opus_bytes));
                    }

                    opus_data.resize(num_opus_bytes);

                    std::vector<unsigned char> packet(12 + opus_data.size() + crypto_secretbox_MACBYTES);

                    packet[0] = 0x80;   //Type
                    packet[1] = 0x78;   //Version

                    packet[2] = _sequence >> 8; //Sequence
                    packet[3] = (unsigned char)_sequence;

                    packet[4] = _timestamp >> 24;   //Timestamp
                    packet[5] = _timestamp >> 16;
                    packet[6] = _timestamp >> 8;
                    packet[7] = _timestamp;

                    packet[8] = (unsigned char)(ssrc >> 24);    //SSRC
                    packet[9] = (unsigned char)(ssrc >> 16);
                    packet[10] = (unsigned char)(ssrc >> 8);
                    packet[11] = (unsigned char)ssrc;

                    _sequence++;
                    _timestamp += SAMPLE_RATE / 1000 * FRAME_MILLIS; //48000Hz / 1000 * 20(ms)

                    unsigned char nonce[crypto_secretbox_NONCEBYTES];
                    memset(nonce, 0, crypto_secretbox_NONCEBYTES);

                    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                        nonce[i] = packet[i];
                    }

                    crypto_secretbox_easy(packet.data() + 12, opus_data.data(), opus_data.size(), nonce, key.data());

                    packet.resize(12 + opus_data.size() + crypto_secretbox_MACBYTES);

                    std::string msg;
                    msg.resize(packet.size(), '\0');

                    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < packet.size(); i++) {
                        msg[i] = packet[i];
                    }
 
                    buffer->push_back(msg);
                }
                run_timer->unset();
                timer.wait();   
                unspeak();
                delete run_timer;
                delete buffer;

                opus_encoder_destroy(encoder);

                delete[] pcm_data;
                });
        }
```

There are 3 possible causes:

1. I send packet late so server-end buffer run out, so the sound produced has some *silence* between each  each 2 packets. Maybe the timer is not accurate so the sound is out of sync.
2. The encode process is wrong which causes lost data somehow.
3. Bad network (i have tested an open source bot written on java, it worked so i can assume that my network is good enough)
   So i post this question, hope someone has experienced this situation show me what wrong and what should i do to correct it.

Comment: Use a packet sniffer like Wireshark and find out more.

Comment: @tadman as i said above, i used a premade bot to test my connection, the result is way better. 
i have just used wireshark and checked RTCP faction lost and there is no difference between premade bot and my bot. So i am pretty sure that there's no problem with my network performance.

Comment: I'm not sure what we can do with this code. This sort of stuff usually requires a lot of in-depth debugging and profiling to get to the core problem. Have you tested just sending through streams of known-good data? Do you have a canned sample you can send that should be received *exactly* the same way each time?

Comment: Tip: Don't forget about things like [`ntohl`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohs) to do endian conversion, or writing functions to dump into the packet/buffer in a particular way that achieves the same thing. Doing this all with a bunch of raw bit shifting seems clunky. Also: `memcpy()` or a C++ alternative like `std::copy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem myself. I want to post solution here for someone who need.
The problem is the timer is unstable so it's usually sleep more than it should, so it makes the music broken.
I changed it to an accurate sleep function which i found somewhere on the internet(i don't remember the source, sorry for that, if you know it please credit it bellow).
Function source code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <window.h>
static void timerSleep(double seconds) {
            using namespace std::chrono;

            static HANDLE timer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
            static double estimate = 5e-3;
            static double mean = 5e-3;
            static double m2 = 0;
            static int64_t count = 1;

            while (seconds - estimate > 1e-7) {
                double toWait = seconds - estimate;
                LARGE_INTEGER due;
                due.QuadPart = -int64_t(toWait * 1e7);
                auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
                SetWaitableTimerEx(timer, &due, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0);
                WaitForSingleObject(timer, INFINITE);
                auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();

                double observed = (end - start).count() / 1e9;
                seconds -= observed;

                ++count;
                double error = observed - toWait;
                double delta = error - mean;
                mean += delta / count;
                m2 += delta * (error - mean);
                double stddev = sqrt(m2 / (count - 1));
                estimate = mean + stddev;
            }

            // spin lock
            auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
            while ((high_resolution_clock::now() - start).count() / 1e9 < seconds);
        }
```

Thank you for your support!